# How do I create displayBlock components in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript

By default, Angular CLI creates components in an inline displayed mode. But it is possible to create components with display: block style using display: Block option. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--display-block` arugment when running `ng generate component <<component name>>`

```
ng g c <<component name>> --display-block
```

#### [---display-block](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component)

> - Specifies if the style will contain :host { display: block; }.
> - Aliases: -b
> - boolean false